# Find first and last values in a column, then take the values next to it

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have two columns: *column A* is a *list of numbers*, while *column B* is *time*. I need to find the first value that isn't a 7 (usually 0) in column A, then take the time next to it.

I've tried using the below but I keep getting N/A:

> =INDEX(H:H,MATCH("0",G:G,0)+0,0,0)

I would also like to find the last value that is not a 7 (could be 1, 2, 3, 5 or 0) and then taking the time on the right, but I'm not sure how to do that, perhaps searching from the bottom up? Would VBA be easier?

The example below, correct responses are highlighted (sorry for formatting).

7 | 0:00:30
7 | 0:01:00
7 | 0:01:30
**0 | 0:02:00**
0 | 0:02:30
0 | 0:03:00
0 | 0:03:30
0 | 0:04:00
2 | 0:04:30
2 | 0:05:00
1 | 0:05:30
2 | 0:06:00
**2 | 0:06:30**
7 | 0:07:00
7 | 0:07:30
7 | 0:08:00

Thanks!

Comment: You're likely getting #N/A because `"0"` is not the same as `0`. A text-that-looks-like-a-number is not the same as a number.

Comment: Yep that was the issue, I was so confused because I've used this formula before!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first is a simple 'find-first-row-matching-a-condition'.

```
=INDEX(B:B, AGGREGATE(15, 7, ROW(A:A)/(A$1:A$16<>7), 1))
```

The second needs to take the first location into consideration.

```
=INDEX(B:B, AGGREGATE(15, 7, ROW(INDEX(A:A, AGGREGATE(15, 7, ROW(A:A)/(A$1:A$16<>7), 1)+1):A$16)/(INDEX(A:A, AGGREGATE(15, 7, ROW(A:A)/(A$1:A$16<>7), 1)+1):A$16=7), 1)-1)
```

For your sample data, this works as well but I would run more tests on other data samples before relying on it. Particularly so if there are 'numbers-that- are-not-7' under the second batch of 7's.

```
=INDEX(B:B, MATCH(6, A:A))
```

[image]

Comment: For the second formula that returns the last row matching the condition, why not use the `14` function number of `AGGREGATE` instead? The formula should then be `=INDEX(B:B, AGGREGATE(14, 7, ROW(A:A)/(A$1:A$16<>7), 1))` which supposedly captures the last row matching the condition.

Comment: I'm concerned the sample data is not representative of the actual data set. I suspect there may be other numbers below the set of 7's.

Comment: Hi Jeeped, the simple formula is working great so far, thank you! Could you explain what the 6 is doing? I'd just like to understand how excel is interpreting that.

Comment: It's finding the last number that is lower than 7.